# Showing $f$ is constant in $D$ if $v=u^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on a group worksheet and none of us know how to approach this problem:

Suppose that $f = u+iv$ is analytic in the domain $D$ and $v=u^2$ in $D$.  Show that $f$ must be constant in $D$.

We know that because it is analytic, than the Cauchy reimann equations are true. But we are not sure how to move from there. Only looking for a hint in which direction to go.

Comment: Hint: substitute $u^2$ for $v$ in the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then combine them into one equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $$u_x = v_y = (u^2)_y = 2uu_y$$

Now use the other Cauchy-Riemann equation to represent $u_y$ in terms of $u$ and $u_x$, and rearrange.

---

Spoiler:

> You should arrive at $(1 + 4u^2) u_y = 0$, so $u_y$ is...?

Comment: Thanks. This was our initial thought, but we tried an example to see if the logic was true and we just ended up confusing ourselves. We have it answered now. Thanks!

Comment: @Blaris You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let's apply Cauchy-Riemann:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

says that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u^2}{\partial y} = 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.\tag{1}$$

Likewise

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

says that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x} = -2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\tag{2}$$

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together gives

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -4u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \Rightarrow (1+4u^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0.$$

Since this holds for all $x$, either $u = \pm\frac{1}{2}i$ (which cannot be the case - why?) or $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$ which says $u$ is constant. Then since $v=u^2$, $v$ must be constant.

Comment: Hi, why can't $u = \pm \frac{1}{2}i$? Wouldn't that show that u is constant, and hence so is v?

Comment: Hah you're right. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Cauchy-Riemann equations we have:
$$
u_x=v_y=2uu_y,\ u_y=-v_x=-2uu_x.
$$
It follows that
$$
u_x=2uu_y=-4u^2u_x,\ u_y=-4u^2u_y,
$$
i.e.
$$
(1+4u^2)u_x=0=(1+4u^2)u_y.
$$
Hence
$$
u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0,
$$
and since $D$ is connected, it follows that $u$ and $v$ are constant. Thus $f$ is constant.